# How to express dependency in a UML Class Diagram?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I the following two classes:

```
class a {
    void foo(){
        b object= new b();
        object.baar();
    }
}
class b {
    void baar(){
    }
}
```

How to express class `a` using class `b` with Class Diagram (which arrow to use)?

Comment: This is a dependency. Use the dashed line with open arrow. See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcdepend.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever one class has a reference/uses another, it is said to have a dependency on it. In your example, class `a` uses class `b`. Therefore class `a` has a dependency on class `b`. For that, you can use the UML dashed line with open arrow as described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html).

This is a very general relationship.

> One class depends on another if the independent class is a parameter
>   variable or local variable of a method of the dependent class.

If your class `a` had an instance variable, you would use the [association link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html) instead.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to put a dashed dependency line, which may be directional or not.

- If class `b` makes use of class `a`, the dependency line should be bidirectional (or directionless)
- If class `b` does not make use of class `a` (except possibly through callbacks not tied directly to `a`) make the dashed line directional from `a` to `b`.

[image: Illustration]